# python XlsxWriter: empty cell format

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am writing a custom wrapper around `xlsxwriter` that will create excel sheets with our company logo and design.

However, every time after file is moved or resaved,
all my stylish empty background is replaced with default white color.

```
background =  workbook.add_format({'pattern':1, 'bg_color':'#f4f4f4'})
self.worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(name)

self.worksheet.set_column(0, 3000, None, background_style)
self.worksheet.insert_image('B2', '../resources/logo.png')
self.worksheet.write('B6', title, title_style)
```

Here I use conditional formatting to achieve background color:

`ws.conditional_format(cell_range, {'type': 'cell',
                                   'criteria': '!=',
                                   'value': -100000,
                                   'format': frmt})`

It looks like the loss of the color happens when either autosave or dropbox sync event happens.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This doesn't sound like any known issue or anything that should happen with XlsxWriter which in most cases creates files which are 100% similar to files created by Excel. Could you add a more complete example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Sure. 
I define background through conditional formatting:

Comment: That still isn't an full but small working example that can. E used to reproduce the error. Without that it is impossible to answer this question since, as I said, it isn't a known XlsxWriter issue.